# Storing iCalendar Exceptions

Tags: icalendar

I'm new to icalendar stuff...pondering how to handle a recurrence rule exception. If I have a daily recurrence rule for a 9:00am event that occurs Mon - Fri, and I want to change the start time of the event on Wed, do I add the occurrence date calculated by rrule for wednesday to exdate and then create an entirely new stand alone event?

The problem I have with that is my "events" are actually work orders that live in separate database documents, so creating a new event this way would break the association between the now standalone workorder and the other instances.

I also considered adding the occurrence date calculated by rrule for Wednesday to exdate and then adding the new date-time to rdate and using it as the recurrenceId for the affected instance, but not sure if that is correct either? Seems like that would work.

Thansk for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create an exception by creating another VEVENT that shares the same `UID`. For example, this is a daily recurring event that has the first wednesday overridden. I removed some of the required properties and added indentation for legibility:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
  BEGIN:VEVENT
    UID:foo-bar
    DTSTART:20141124T090000Z
    RRULE:FREQ=DAILY
  END:VEVENT
  BEGIN:VEVENT
    UID:foo-bar
    RECURRENCE-ID:20141126T090000Z
    DTSTART:20141126T100000Z
  END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

In the second VEVENT we refer to the *old time* using `RECURRENCE-ID` and then override the time with a new `DTSTART`.

Comment: Think I understand...so okay to use UID for multiple instances of a repeating event because it's still considered 1 event? Should I also add the old recurrence-id to exdate on the original event to prevent rrule from calculating an instance for that date? Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know if you can call a recurring event technically '1 event', but yes they are connected. No, you don't need to list it in `EXDATE`.